# How to create a batch file for executing command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Bellow is my command which is working fine. But for that every time I need to open my command prompt and need to type the command.

I want to create a batch file for these command and just on click of this batch file I want to execute the command.

```
My command is,
c:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mysharewifi key=mypassword
c:\Windows\system32>start netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is extremely easy to find on the Internet. I'm sure you'll get answers, but you might be able to find quicker by searching with Google. Start with how to create and then try to use what you have learned to create what you want. When you have exhausted all your avenues then come to StackOverflow and post what you have tried.

Comment: I have already tried but none of them working. I kept like "START my command" but its not working. @MichaelZ.

Comment: What happens if you add the full path to cmd.exe? C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe> your command.

Comment: My command is --> C:\windows\system32> my command @MichaelZ.

Comment: Do like this `start cmd.exe /k "your command"`

Comment: thanks its working. @MichaelZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
start cmd.exe /k "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=mysharewifi key=mypassword"
start cmd.exe /k "start netsh wlan start hostednetwork"
```